# Android Image View Failed to instantiate one or more classes

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to add image to my Activity through image viewer.

However, I keep receiving Render error that says "Failed to instantiate one or more classes"

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/NACT Engineering Logo"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="95dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="505dp" />
```

"@drawable/NACT Engineering Logo" is highlighted in red. I have no idea why.. 
When I hover my mouse over it, it says '' is not a valid resource name character

Please help!

Comment: You should be posting the error shown. You can hover the highlighted line to know what the error is.

Comment: @KrishnaPradyumnaMokshagundam Sorry, I just added it in.

Comment: Please remove spaces in the file name and change the name in the `<ImageView>` tag appropriately.

Comment: @KrishnaPradyumnaMokshagundam It was the problem with the spaces in my file name. Thanks! I couldn't find what was wrong lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resource file with blank spaces and capital letters in their name are not supported. Try renaming your drawable file to, `nact_engineering_logo`

Comment: Damn, sorry I didnt know that. It works now! Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write this:

```
android:src="@drawable/NACT Engineering Logo"
```

instead of

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/NACT Engineering Logo"
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. Gives the error, '' is not a valid resource name character

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/lauzaviete"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp" />
```

Comment: you need to remove <ImageView only, the body of that ImageView would remain the same.